# SQL many-to-one data retrieval (variable number of virtual columns?)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Several data in table B refer to one datum in table A (specifically so an item in A can be associated with several names/aliases in B).

When retrieving items from A, is there a way to also retrieve all associated items from B in the same row? E.g.

```
A1, B1, B2, B3
A2, B4
A3, B5, B6
```

Or are multiple queries required (get A and then B for each A)?

I am currently using SQLite with Python.

---

Here's some code to play with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

try:
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE A (id int, data text)''')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'A1')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO A VALUES (2, 'A2')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO A VALUES (3, 'A3')")

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE B (id int, rel int, data text)''')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 1, 'B1')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 1, 'B2')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 1, 'B3')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (4, 2, 'B4')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (5, 3, 'B5')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO B VALUES (6, 3, 'B6')")

    conn.commit()
except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
    pass

c.execute('''
    SELECT a.data, b.data 
    FROM a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.rel
    --WHERE a.id=?'''#, (1,)
    )
print(c.fetchall())

conn.close()
```

It already returns a list of all the combinations:

```
[('A1', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B4'), ('A3', 'B5'), ('A3', 'B6')]
```

That would be easy to iterate already.

However, I was looking for something like:

```
[('A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B4'), ('A3', 'B5', 'B6')]
```

I'll now look into GROUP_CONCAT as suggested by [MEdwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301143/sql-many-to-one-data-retrieval-variable-number-of-virtual-columns#comment104805356_59301143).

---

Using

```
SELECT a.data, GROUP_CONCAT(b.data)
```

results in

```
[('A1', 'B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6')]
```

which is not what I would like to achieve. Could you please elaborate?

---

Try it online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2cade/1

Comment: Yes. it is possible. if you showed us a sample of data and what you have done, we could have help modified it. But what you need is the function `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @MEdwin I'll add an [mcve].

Comment: The result of a query in relational databases is a table. But you request a result which is not a table (it has a different number of values in each row). You need to go to JSON output or something similar or you have to be satisfied with the aggregated result returned by `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: @MEdwin I've added data / an example - could you have another look and elaborate on your comment please?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be NO.

Here's one way of converting the `[(key, value), ... ]` tuples of the resulting rows into a `{key:[value, ...], ...}` dict.

```
... # see code in question
input = c.fetchall()
output = {}
for e in input:
    if e[0] in output:
        output[e[0]].append( e[1] )
    else:
        output[e[0]] = [e[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `LEFT JOIN` you can `group by A.id, A.data` and then use (conditionally just in case there is no matching `rel` in table `B`) `group_concat()`:

```
select 
  A.data || 
  case 
    when count(B.data) = 0 then ''
    else ',' || group_concat(B.data)
  end data
from A left join B on B.rel = A.id
group by A.id, A.data
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phQGKxqMUS6nxXG8NiJx9C/8).
Results:

```
| data        |
| ----------- |
| A1,B1,B2,B3 |
| A2,B4       |
| A3,B5,B6    |
```